# Where can I get Jones in the Fast Lane?

Tags: jones-in-the-fast-lane

Sierra had a 1990 game called Jones in the Fast Lane which my family used to have the CD for but now it's been lost. Does anyone know of a legal way to get this game other than buying an old CD off of Ebay?

Comment: I've once again removed the [old-games] tag from this question; that tag, as it mentions in its tag wiki, is for compatibility questions, not a catch-all for any game that came out more than a decade ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I loved that game, but also no longer have my original copy (floppy version). While using eBay/Amazon/etc is probably the easiest (and most expensive) way to find the game, there are a couple other options:

- Try the **[flash version](http://home.broadpark.no/~kboye/jones/jones.html)**.
- Wait and hope for it to appear on a digital distribution site (probably **[GOG](http://www.gog.com)**).
- Hope to get incredibly lucky at a used games bin in a brick-and-mortar store. For a game like Jones, unfortunately that doesn't seem very likely.

**Edit:** You can go **[here](http://www.gog.com/en/wanted)** and vote for Jones in the Fast Lane as a game you'd like to see on GOG. Take action for your cause!

Comment: There's a flash version!? I wish I could give you more than one upvote.

Comment: You can now also visit https://jonesinthefastlane.com/ to play it if you wish.

Answer (score -3):

For the time being, it is Abandonware.

Downloadable at:
http://www.abandonia.com/en/games/40/Jones+in+the+Fast+Lane.html

Comment: Abandonware is *not* legal, as much as people think it is.